# why some images are not displayed?

Tags: html, angular, image, sass

I have two different projects (PWA and a webpage):

`<img [src]="fileFirebaseUrl" class="image">`

`<div [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + imageURL + ')'}">`

Some images are not displaying correctly, when I inspect the *html* I can't find any background properties set. I have tried with svg, jpeg and png.

Some images work when I transform them to another format, or when I export a new image with another format.

Answer (score 0):

Background image is not same as image tag. So it's repeated by default and position is not correct. So you should do like the following:

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'background': 'url(' + imageURL + ') no-repeat 0 0'}"></div>
```

No `background-image`, use `background` for all-in-one styling. Otherwise, you can use `background-repeat`, `background-position`, `background-size` etc separately.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with this function (trim is for possible linebreaks)

```
getCssUrl(url: string) {
    if (url) {
      return 'url(\'' + url.trim() + '\')';
    }
  }
```